# Detect swipe on ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

How do i detect swipe up and down on a listView. I have tried the following methods

1. Using onSimpleGestureListener,onFling() works for fling( i.e when i leave the screen after swipe). But it doesnt get called on swipe( finger not lifted from screen finally).

2.In onScroll() of onSimpleGestureListener, distanceY is not helpful for detecting up and down swipe. It works fine for fling detection, but fluctuates its values from negative to positive in a particular swipe.

3. Using onTouchListener

   ```
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

           return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
           switch (event.getAction()) {

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                   before = event.getY();
                   break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                   now = event.getY();

                   if (now < before) {

                          upSwipe()  

                   } else if (now > before) {

                          downSwipe();

                  } 

           }
           return false;
       }
   ```

   When i swipe up, variable `now` sometimes becomes greater than variable `previous` and sometimes small. So both upSwipe() and downSwipe() is called.

I am banging my head for hours. Not able to sole this.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to return true instead of returning false.

Based on the [Detecting Common Gestures documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html).

"Beware of creating a listener that returns false for the ACTION_DOWN event. If you do this, the listener will not be called for the subsequent ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP string of events. This is because ACTION_DOWN is the starting point for all touch events."